# Is there an idiom for something that is being fought-over?

Tags: idioms, american-english, idiom-request

What idioms describe something that's really popular and is being fought-over by many different people?

Comment: Is it the very last Turbo Man?

Comment: hot finger lickin' chicken with extra BBQ sauce

Comment: If you can find one older word or phrase with the meaning you want, you can look that word up in a thesaurus.

Comment: In American football, a "loose ball" will be fought over by as many players as can reach it.  Up to 22 guys can be "in the pile" trying to get control of the football.

Comment: "[Maguffin](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MacGuffin)" is a general term for a "a mysterious package/artifact/superweapon that everyone in the story is chasing."

Comment: It would appear to kind of depend on whether the 'something' is food, a football, a movie plot, or the middle east. i.e. there's no real answer without clarification of the question

Comment: @Jasper But a maguffin is specifically something that serves no purpose other than to drive the plot forward. Many things (e.g., territory) are fought over because they have intrinsic value.

Comment: The last (insert popular toy name) on Black Friday.

Comment: This question got put on hold because it's a bit vague. If you explain a little more about what kind of sought-after thing you are trying to describe, we can reopen the question. As it is, you could be talking about a toy in a store, a ball on a playing field, a job opening in a town with a depressed economy, or a treasure in a pirate movie. One idiom won't necessarily cover all four of those.

Answer (score 1):

"the latest bone of contention" - the latest topic about which people are arguing. The metaphor here is of two dogs fighting for the same bone. I added "latest" to get to your intended meaning of "popular", but I'll have to think of more related expressions.

You could also be like most journalists and overload the poor word "controversy" with all kinds of connotations related to popularity :)

Comment: This is usually a term used in a negotiation situation.

Comment: I've seen it used (and used it myself) in a variety of situations, one of which could be a negotiation. I work in software, and they're always looking for "resourceful developers", meaning developers that can find ways to solve problems.